# Dynamically load and built in code from source file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want my AS3 game to have different types of monsters with different functionality. I want to implement this functionality in AS3 language as separate classes for all enemies and store those classes at the server as scripts.

Later, when my client loads, I want it to download those "Monster" classes from the server, parse them and build them into my current application. "Monster" classes are going to utilize some client classes, because they will need to affect the world (sprites of the application really).

To give you some understanding of what I want to achieve take a look at the following links of LUA interpreter for AS3:
http://www.cmodule.org/lua/
and
http://lua-alchemy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/index.html

How can I achieve that? Please point me to some libraries/projects or workarounds for my issue.

Comment: You don't need any workarounds. You can simply package your monsters in separate compiled swf files, which you load dynamically (remotely or locally). You define a common interface that your game will access and that's it.

Comment: @jpop what if I need to use some global variables from my main SWF in that remote SWF?

Comment: I think that's a security issue and so not allowed. That's for sure on mobile, on the web you can maybe work around that with crossdomain policies. But, main SWF can access everything in the remote SWF, so it can read/write variables in it. So you can achieve pretty much what you need by reversing the relationship.

Comment: How about using sprite sheets ? take a look at Starling framework and assets loading.